# ErrorException during php artisan optimize

Tags: php

When I tried `php artisan optimize` then I am getting below error.

```
"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Declaration of Carbon\\Carbon::setTime($hour,
 $minute, $second = 0) should be compatible with DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second
 = NULL, $microseconds = NULL)","file":"\/Users\/asrinivasarao\/Projects\/git\/xyz\/src\/vendor\/nesbot\/carbon\/src\/Carbon\/Carbon.php","line":681}}%
```

How to fix it?